# The panel encountered a problem while loading "IndicatorAppletCompleteFactory::IndicatorAppletComplete" error when using xrdp and mate

Tags: 20.04, mate, xrdp

I am running an Ubuntu 20.04 image from AWS:

```
$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:        20.04
Codename:       focal
```

I have installed xrdp and mate on this instance:

```
# Install xrdp
sudo apt-get install xrdp=0.9.12-1 -y

# Install mate
sudo apt-get install mate-desktop-environment=1.24.0+1 -y

# Configure xrdp to use mate
echo "mate-session" > $HOME/.xsession
```

when I log in, I see this window:

[image]

how can I fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by installing `mate-desktop-environment-extras`:

```
$ sudo apt-get install mate-desktop-environment-extras=1.24.0+1 -y
```

Comment: Installation of minimal Ubuntu MATE task by `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-mate-core^` will provide better user experience.